# Laravel 5.1 Configuration Session Lifetime Apply Changes

Tags: laravel, session, laravel-5.1

simple question here. In my laravel `config/session.php` I have changed the lifetime value from the default 2 hours to this:

```
 /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Session Lifetime
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may specify the number of minutes that you wish the session
    | to be allowed to remain idle before it expires. If you want them
    | to immediately expire on the browser closing, set that option.
    |
    */

    'lifetime' => 1440,

    'expire_on_close' => true,

    /*
```

However, even though this is what I have on my server, it still sticks to the default 2 hour session. I can verify this by seeing the cookie `laravel_session` which always maxes out in 2 hours.

What am I missing? Is there a separate configuration file or value I need to change to apply my new `lifetime`?

**Edit:** Well apparently you can't expect both the `lifetime` and the `expire_on_close` option to both be operating at the same time because they utilize two different types of cookies, but I still don't understand why if I have the `expire_on_close` set to `true` why my cookie is expiring in 2 hours rather than when the browsing session ends?

Comment: Did you increase session time in php.ini file on the server?

Comment: Nope I will do that now and try.

Comment: @RohitKhatri What value do I change? `session.gc_maxlifetime` is already less than 2 hours, I don't see a value that is set for 2 hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`php artisan config:cache` applies changes to the configuration files!