# laravel sessions and lifetime

Tags: laravel, session

Here I store user id in Laravel sessions and I have set the life time to 1 hour in config file but its not  clear the session in a hour. I want to clear this user id from the session in a hour how can I do this? After expiration time of session does it make my session variable null?

**Config session.php file**

[image: Screen Shot]

**Here i put variable into session**

[image: Screen Shot]

what is wrong with this?

Comment: after changing app..php have you run `php artisan config:clear` ? or run again `php artisan optimize:clear`

Comment: yes i tried it but its not working

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38816329/laravel-5-1-configuration-session-lifetime-apply-changes

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code/errors.  Edit your question and add the relevant code as text.

Comment: K sry for the inconvenience